# How could i rename android studio package

Tags: android, package

I have a problem - I am trying to rename the packages of my Android application with Android Studio, but it turns out that following the steps of other guides after giving refactor does not give me the option to rename the package.

Instead it gives me to rename the directory directly and I don't know what to do with that.

[There is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIuSj.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename package in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio)

Comment: I can't really do any of the solutions in that post because as I said, the option to rename package does not appear, it just tells me to rename directory

Comment: Check this link I think it will help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/rename-package-in-android-studio

Comment: The same, than the first comment

Answer (score 0):

Please rename it properly, I too came across this issues. I tried restarting and clearing the cache and rebuild the file. The new edition of android studio has different steps for renaming the package.

Steps:

Then right click > refactor > rename
[image]

Then choose project from the provided options.
[image]

On the top left corner search for the chosen option called android, select it.
[image]